# Error in " I asked for his book, but he did not lend me."

Tags: error

> I asked for his book, but he did not lend me.

What is the error in this sentence?

I have read on a website that--Personal pronouns come directly after the verb “lend.”  So maybe **"lend me"** is correct.

Comment: ***to lend*** is a ***ditransitive*** verb, like ***to give***. It normally requires both direct and indirect object, as in ***Lend me your ears, Give me your attention*** (direct object ***me***, indirect object ***your ears / attention***).  On those rare occasions when the verb is used ***monotransitively*** (with only ***one*** object), the single object explicitly specified must always be the ***direct*** object *(He gives **piano lessons**,  They lend **venture capital**)*. So in your example, with only one explicit object, *I asked for his book, but he would not lend **it***.

Comment: Compare *I asked him for the book, but he said he never lends **books*** (only one object, no preposition required because it's the ***direct*** object) and *I asked him for the book, but he said he never lends **to friends*** (again, only one object, but this time the preposition is required because it's the ***indirect*** object).

Comment: You've inverted *direct* and *indirect* in your first comment, @FumbleFingers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A very humble query, if I may: In the sentence: **Give me your attention.** is **me** not the indirect object and **your attention** (the thing to be given) not the direct object - as per ** Give him the  book**.

Comment: @RonaldSole, Gary Botnovcan: I should have had the courage of my convictions! I did originally write *the single object ... must always be the **indirect** object* in the first comment. Then after wondering whether I'd mixed them up I did a quick google search for "give him the ball direct indirect object", and somehow convinced myself to delete ***in***. I may have been inconsistent anyway, so unilaterally changing ***direct*** to ***indirect*** (and vice-versa) in my two comments might still leave errors. But the basic point should still be valid (even though ***in-*** is misplaced! :)

Comment: ...that's to say I can *give John piano lessons* or simply *give piano lessons*, but unless I was some kind of latter-day slave trader, I couldn't just *give John*.

Answer (score 1):

You lend *something* to *someone*. You need 'lend me **it**' or 'lend **it** to me'.

> lend
>
> verb     A2 [ transitive ]   to give something to someone for a short
> period of time, expecting it to be given back:
>
> She doesn't like lending her books.
>
> **[ + two objects ] If you need a coat I can lend you one/lend one to you.**

[Lend (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/lend)